# How do I use the "Google Workspace Developper Preview Program" javascript libraries?

Tags: google-workspace, google-chat

I'm part of the "*Google Workspace Developper Preview Program*" and have access to the preview "libraries". But I'm unable to find any place where they explain how to use those libraries (I'm using ts/js).

**Could someone provide guidance on how to use them, please?**

My goal is to try the feature of creating a Google Chat Space using a Service Account (with no delegation)

Answer (score -1):

To use "Google workspace developper program"Java script libraries consult the given documentation process,configuration and user details then import libraries,initialize with required settings and refer to API references for complete implementation

Comment: That's all my point.. there isn't any documentation available, as far as I know. 
If you have any clue where it is, please share

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).